# tensorflow Embedding layer keeps dropping batch size to half

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I am building a tensorflow model in google colab.
i get confused with the behaviour of the embedding layer. it keeps dropping the input layer size to half.

```
def build_model(vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units, batch_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim,
                              batch_input_shape=[batch_size, 100]),
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
  ])
  return model

model = build_model(
  vocab_size = len(vocab),
  embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
  rnn_units=rnn_units,
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss)
```

and here is the input.

```
dataset = helperDf(df, 64,100)
```

dataset is a batch helper class. everytime it is called, it return array with two tensor with size [(64,100),(64,100)] for train and label.

calling

```
example_batch_predictions = model(dataset.batch())


print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")
```

return fine. with 
`(64, 100, 48) # (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)`

however when I call :

```
history = model.fit(dataset.batch(), epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

It return :

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (64, 100) for input Tensor("embedding_4_input:0", shape=(64, 100), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 100).
```

why it detects the input as 32 not 64 ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably your whole dataset doesn't have a number of samples that is a multiple of 64. 
The last batch may be smaller.

If that's the case, it's clear that your dataset is a multiple of 32, though, and you could try to use a batch size of 32 (both in the dataset iterator and in the model) to check if this is the problem.

Since you're using `stateful=True` and the batch size is required, then you need to treat the dataset. If you do want 64, you will probably need to either create 32 more examples (maybe you copy a few examples of underrepresented classes) or you remove 32 samples (preferrably from the overrepresented classes).

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem myself. like a generator. my class need to adapt with :

**iter**()

and

**next**()